# Strategies for overriding database.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, yaml

In my environment, the deployment servers have much of the connection information that is in the database.yml. That is, they know whether they are development, test or production servers, and they know their respective database connection information.

I can encapsulate this information in a Server class for example, so that I can retrieve the information:

```
Server["environment"] #=> production
Server["db_host"] #=> db5.example.com
Server["db_password"] #=> [a decrypted password]
```

and so on. I would like to deploy a Rails application and have it autoconfigure based on the Server settings. What is the best way to do this?

One way to do this is Erb in my database.yml:

```
<%= Server["environment"] %>: 
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  host: <%= Server["db_host"] %>
  username: db_user 
  password: <%= Server["password"] %>
```

I'm not too thrilled about doing it this way, but it would work. In this case, where would I put the 'server.rb' that defines the Server class--require it here in the yml? app/initializers gets loaded after ActiveRecord loads database.yml.

Another possible solution is to somehow override railties' database initializer:

```
# File railties/lib/initializer.rb, line 903
def database_configuration
  require 'erb'
  YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(database_configuration_file)).result)
end
```

The above is called only if :active_record is defined in config.frameworks. I'm not sure how I would go about overriding this early enough in the Rails startup sequence.

Maybe a third option is to *remove* :active_record from config.frameworks, and then create the connection later, say in the app initializers? I'm afraid this may have lots of unintended side effects.

I'm *hoping* that there's something simple and obvious that I haven't found, such as an ActiveRecord feature that allows me to opt out of database.yml and provide alternate config programmatically.

Comment: My hope for a built-in solution is dashed. Evidently there was discussion on the Rails core team a couple years ago over a patch that provided a ruby alternative to database.yml, and it had some support, but it was rejected. http://www.mail-archive.com/rubyonrails-core@googlegroups.com/msg06694.html

Comment: Note: as of Rails 3.1.2, that `database_configuration` method is located  in `Rails::Application::Configuration`.  In previous versions, it was in `Rails::Configuration`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's two tricks which might help here. One is what you've touched on, that being monkey-patching the routine that loads in the database configuration, and that's certainly something worth exploring. The nice thing about Ruby is you can pretty much patch out anything you don't like and replace it with something better. The liability here is that a newer version of Rails might use a different mechanism for configuration and your patch will cause everything to break. Maybe that's a price worth paying.

The other approach is to keep the `database.yml` file on the server instead of in your repository, and have some kind of deployment script that links it in to the appropriate location. The advantage to this approach is you don't have important passwords floating around in your version control system and you can update a server's configuration without having to patch the application.

Comment: There's always preinitializer which you could use to load you server class, and use that from database.yml.

Comment: @François That's interesting. I didn't know about the preinitializer. Thanks!

Comment: Any ideas where I'd be able to monkey-patch ActiveRecord? I have to do this after AR loads but before the connection is made.

Comment: Since `config/preinitializer.rb` was deprecated, the official method for this sort of thing is to put your hook in `config/application.rb` right after `require "rails/all"`

Comment: upvoting the *other* approach

Answer (score 18):

You can provide your own database customizations directly in your application.rb:
It seems to work nice rails 3.2. (Be warned though, it's a kind-of monkey patching)

```
module MyApp 
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ... config 
    config.encoding = "utf-8" 

    def config.database_configuration
      parsed = super
      raise parsed.to_yaml  # Replace this line to add custom connections to the hash from database.yml
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Was working until ruby1.9.3 and then i updated to ruby 2.3.x and its throwing error saying super cannot be called on NoMethodError: super: no superclass method `database_configuration'. I will make a question on this

Answer (score 18):

This seems to work in Rails 3.2.2

```
module MyApp 
  class Application < Rails::Application
    self.paths['config/database'] = 'config/another_db.yml'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a simple way to point to another database.yml. In my case, however, it doesn't buy me much because I don't want things hardcoded (especially production password) so I would still need Erb in it.

Comment: In my case, I set different .yml's for different environments. I still like having file config in files, some of which might be in my source repo (i.e. development using sqlite3), but production being configured   manually on the server.

Comment: Thanks. Adding `self.paths['config/database'] = 'config/another_db.yml'` in application.rb works for Rails3.

Comment: This works great. An app I'm working on has to run on Ubuntu (via Vagrant), but I frequently want to run it in OSX as well while developing. So a simple `ENV` check in `config/environments/development.rb` is great to switch out the database config when running in OSX

Comment: Here's documentation of the `Rails::Paths::Root` class of which `Rails.application.paths` (or `self.paths` as referenced above) is an instance: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Paths/Root.html - and here is the list of default paths: http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Application/Configuration/paths

Answer (score 16):

This is an old question, but in Rails 4 you can simply use an environment variable and have a blank or missing database.yml (`DATABASE_URL` will override any database.yml)

`DATABASE_URL=postgres://myuser:mypass@myposgresbox.com:5432/my-database-name`

more here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#connection-preference

Comment: this is what I needed for a devops use-case