# Strategies for overriding database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, yaml, erb

There is another question on stackoverflow with this title. This is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204724/strategies-for-overriding-database-yml) to that. My question is a little different but almost on the same line

I work with a database that has multiple users each having a unique set of privileges to the database. Hence I can't hard code the database login details in the database.yml. Instead I want to create a html form which collects the login credentials. I understand that database.yml can be written in the erb way from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204724/strategies-for-overriding-database-yml). But by the time, my index.html(the page in which I have written my form) is shown, the attempt to establish connection is done and it is throwing an error saying nil is provided for username and password. Please let me know how to approach this problem.

I am new to rails, so please ask me if I didn't provide enough information. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ActiveRecord::ConnectionHandling.establish_connection](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling/establish_connection) function call to connect to your database.  You should be able to establish a connection with a different user even on every page if you would like, or look up the database credentials in a User model.

If you are doing this, you might consider subclassing `ActiveRecord::Base` and overriding the `connection` call, which would then be used by every model to connect to the database.

If you want to completely avoid a connection to the database before you explicitly set up the credentials through your application, then you probably want to initialize Rails without loading all of the ActiveRecord specific stuff.  In that case, you will need to remove ActiveRecord from the initialization of Rails by putting this line in your `config/environment.rb`, within the `Rails::Initializer.run do |config|` block:

```
config.frameworks -= [ :active_record ]
```

Then you will need to load all of the ActiveRecord specific things once you have the credentials.

Alternatively, you can override `Rails::Initialize::initialize_database` which is where the actual database connection is being used by putting this in your environment.rb before the `Rails::Initializer.run` call:

```
module Rails
  class Initializer
    def initialize_database
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

Prior to rails 4.x you would use [ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class), which is now deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am able to get over the issue by using ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection like you suggested. I am going to try overriding connection call in ActiveRecord::Base. Before that I have a doubt.
If I am collecting the login details from a html form, the overriding happens in the form controller. Before the form is hit, won't rails try to use database.yml which is empty now?

Comment: If you don't use any models when getting to that form, then you shouldn't have a problem.  ActiveRecord will not connect to the database unless you create an instance of it.

Comment: Couldn't resist but testing what you just said. I deleted the contents of the database.yml and started the server. The server didn't start with this error(I am adding the error to the question)

Comment: Thanks. My bad actually. It is working. I shouldn't have emptied the contents of database.yml. I just had to remove the username and password from the database.yml. I will try overriding the connection call and post here whether it worked or not.

Comment: I updated the question a little more, to make it easier if you don't have a database.yml at all you can skip the initialize_database part of the initializer by overriding it.  That would be useful if you don't even know the database name.