# bashrc environment variables not working with Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, ruby-on-rails-4

I have setup variables in my ~/.bashrc file that I would like to use with my Rails app.  The problem is Rails will not recognize these variables.

**bashrc:**

```
export MYSQL_DB_USERNAME=admin
export MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD=testing123
```

**Rails app - database.yml**

```
  username: <%= ENV["MYSQL_DB_USERNAME"] %>
  password: <%= ENV["MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD"] %>
```

If I go into the rails console and type:

```
ENV["MYSQL_DB_USERNAME"]
```

I get back:   `<= nil`

I've reloaded my bashrc file and restarted the terminal.  Neither worked.  Why won't Rails read these variables from the bashrc file?

(I am using RVM for ruby version management, in case that matters).

Thanks.

Comment: can you use erb inside your database yml? See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204724/strategies-for-overriding-database-yml

Comment: Could you try to specify the variables in the command line just to see what happens? Ex: `FOO=bar ruby -e "puts ENV['FOO']"`

Comment: Just to make sure: did you `source ~/.bashrc` before running `rails console`?

Comment: @victor - yes that works in the regular command line.

Comment: So I believe there is something wrong with your .bashrc - somehow it's not being loaded. The Rails/Ruby code seems fine.

Comment: @vee - i swear i tried that, of course, now it is working.  Question though - when I restart the terminal, it stops working until I rerun ```source ~/.bashrc```.  Do i need that line in my bashrc file too?

Comment: I added ```source ~/.bashrc``` to the end of my bash_profile.  Is that a good idea?

Comment: @productionQA, yes source ~/.bashrc in profile.  Take a [read here on bash_profile vs bashrc](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html).  It shows you recommendation to maintain the two as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can put your setting at the top of ~/.bashrc.

Because mina uses ssh in non-interactive mode.
In the first files of .bashrc, it has

```
#If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

The settings below this line will be ignored.

Comment: I put the declaration of my variables at the beginning of the ~/.bashrc file and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you are running the rails app.

For example if you did

```
export MYSQL_DB_USERNAME=admin
export MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD=testing123
rails console
> ENV["MYSQL_DB_USERNAME"]
```

Then most likely your code would work. If you are starting the railsapp as a different user, or as a daemon/service, then it won't share the same environment and the environment variables you created won't be set anymore.

In my opinion, the best way to set variables is to create a yaml config file. You can do /etc/myapp/config.yml and inside it set the following

`MYSQL_DB_USERNAME: admin
MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD: testing123`

This should be more cleaner than storing the user_name/password inside your `.bashrc` file since you can allow only the rails user to reading this through file permissions - you don't want to play with the file permissions of your `.bashrc`.

Comment: Martin - appreciate the reply!  I figured it all out.  Some dumb order of operations stuff.

Comment: Any chance you can share your solution. I'm having the same issues myself